# Remote Login to firewalled server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

We are a very small startup (.net) with a dev team of 3 that previous had only a single webserver with both the application and database. To improve the security in our infrastructure, I've added our sql server database to a separate windows server, that's connected to our application server via VLAN connection.  Everything is working correctly, but we want also want to prevent anyone trying to connect to the database server through the internet.  The problem is, our development team needs remote access to this server.  These devs work from home, and are not able to obtain static IP's so we can't add a rule to the firewall allowing their ip's access. Is there a solution (vpn etc.) or product I could use that would allow them to access remotely while keeping the server closed to external traffic?

Comment: `Is there a solution (vpn etc.)`  Yes, a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Having your devs use a VPN when access to the LAN is needed is the safest, most secure way.  What kind of firewall are you using right now?  It very well might already support a few concurrent tunnels in which case you're golden.